# Memoirs - What's Allowed To Write About An Ex

Tags: libel, publishing

I'm not famous.  I've just had a very interesting life story so far.  I wish to publish certain aspects of my life, it covers all aspects of my life and includes some chapters about significant ex-partners.

When everything I've written is true, do I have to prove it to be true or will they have to prove it false?

Can you please use simple words in your answer?  I've no idea who the 'defendant' or 'plaintiff' or other legal terms are :/

Comment: What is your jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

See the material in [this Q&A](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/85996/46948).

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Once a statement is shown to be defamatory, the burden is on the [defendant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defendant) to show that it is true, as a defence. See *Grant v. Torstar*, 2009 SCC 61 at paras. 28–29.

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

The [plaintiff](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintiff) must prove that the defamatory statement is also false. See for example, *Pegasus v. Reno Newspapers, Inc.*, 118 Nev. 706 (Nev. 2003):

> The general elements of a defamation claim require a plaintiff to prove: "(1) a false **and** defamatory statement...

Comment: I've given her a copy of the words I say about her, and she raises an 'objection' to using her real name, town, etc.  But it's all true.  One cannot claim the written truth to be libel, can they?  Well, they may claim it, but who would have to provide the proof?  Me, that it's the truth, or her that that they're lies?
Jurisdiction:  This is a complex one:  Me: Brit nationality in Czech Republic.  Her: Czech nationality in Britain.
I sai that my life is interesting :)

Comment: @KenAlton the answer says that "burden [of proof] is on the defendant". That applies in most jurisdictions.