# Opinion vs Defamation

Tags: freedom-of-speech, defamation

Alex Jones was fined over $1 billion for defaming Sandy Hook parents. I don't know the details, but I believe the essence of the case is that he claimed certain individuals were involved in a conspiracy.

Could Jones have avoided a lawsuit if he had prefaced his claims with any of the following?:

1. I believe (so and so was part of a conspiracy).
2. I think . . .
3. In my opinion . . .
4. Many people believe . . .
5. There is evidence to suggest . . .

I thought these would all be protected as free speech, but I read somewhere that the words "in my opinion" are no defense against defamation lawsuits.

Comment: See also: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92673/can-hypothesis-publishing-make-one-liable-for-defamation

Comment: OK, I checked out your link, and I think that does answer it.